# Kotlin: Why can't I do an assignment in a loop guard?

Tags: java, kotlin

Why is this syntax not valid? The error IntelliJ reports is that only expressions are allowed in such context (line 2). I am wondering if there is some syntax to use to get around this, as Java allowed this type of assignment in loop feature.

```
var c: Int;
while ((c = reader.read()) != 1) {
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `reader`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is not valid, because `c = reader.read()` is not an expression in Kotlin – this prevents all the `==` vs `=` bugs.

You have to rewrite it as:

```
while (true) {
    val c = reader.read()
    if (c == 1) break
    ...
}
```

Comment: There are library utilities to read from streams and readers. No need for doing it manually.

Comment: You can avoid `while (true)` @Jire by writing extension functions just as the Kotlin stdlib has done.  I posted an example of doing so in another answer.

Answer (score 8):

***Note:*** *The other answer explains the problem with your syntax, here is an alternative to using the `while` loop.*

A great thing about Kotlin is that you can change your own world to be exactly the way you want it.  So let's create an extension function to do what basically is in the other answers, but making it more appealing.

With this extension function:

```
inline fun Reader.readWhile(crossinline predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Sequence<Char> {
    return generateSequence {
        val c = this.read()
        if (c != -1 && predicate(c)) {
            c.toChar()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

You can now simply:

```
reader.readWhile { it != 1 }.forEach {
   // do something with each char
}
```

And if you want to auto close the reader:

```
reader.use {
    reader.readWhile { it != 1 }.forEach {
       // do something with each char
    }
}
```

And of course you decide if the sequence is of `Char` or `Int` depending on your needs.  You could create your own `useChars` or `forEachChar` or whatever makes your code the way you want it to be.  Look at the [Kotlin API Refrence for kotlin.io](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) for examples of other extensions, [especially on `Reader`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/index.html) for ideas.

### Unit Test

A unit test for the extension function:

```
@Test fun testSo32596261() {
    val reader = CharArrayReader(charArrayOf('A', 'B', 'C', 1.toChar(), 'D', 'E', 'F'))
    reader.use {
        assertEquals(listOf('A', 'B', 'C'), reader.readWhile { it != 1 }.toList())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use something like this

```
val reader = BufferedReader(null)
var line: String? = null
while ({ line = reader.readLine(); line }() != null) {
    println(line)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is much cleaner way to work with Reader in kotlin - ["forEachLine" extension function](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html)

```
val writer = StringWriter()
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"))
reader.forEachLine { writer.write(it) }
```