# How to convert Java assignment expression to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Something in java like

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 1;
if ((a = b) !=c){
    System.out.print(true);
}
```

now it should be converted to kotlin like

```
var a:Int? = 1
var b:Int? = 2
var c:Int? = 1
if ( (a = b) != c)
    print(true)
```

but it's not correct.

Here is the error I get:

```
in " (a=b)" Error:(99, 9) Kotlin: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context
```

Actually the code above is just an example to clarify the problem. Here is my original code:

```
fun readFile(path: String): Unit { 
    var input: InputStream = FileInputStream(path) 
    var string: String = "" 
    var tmp: Int = -1 
    var bytes: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024) 

    while((tmp=input.read(bytes))!=-1) { } 
}
```

Comment: What error (or errors) are you getting?

Comment: in    " (a=b)"      Error:(99, 9) Kotlin: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @AndroidEx correctly stated, assignments are not expressions in Kotlin, unlike Java. The reason is that expressions with side effects are generally discouraged. See [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339/5?u=h0tk3y) on a similar topic.

One solution is just to split the expression and move the assignment out of condition block:

```
a = b
if (a != c) { ... }
```

Another one is to use functions from stdlib like [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), which executes the lambda with the receiver as parameter and returns the lambda result. `apply` and `run` have similar semantics.

```
if (b.let { a = it; it != c }) { ... }
```

```
if (run { a = b; b != c }) { ... }
```

Thanks to [inlining](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions), this will be as efficient as plain code taken from the lambda.

---

Your example with `InputStream` would look like

```
while (input.read(bytes).let { tmp = it; it != -1 }) { ... }
```

Also, consider [`readBytes`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/read-bytes.html) function for reading a `ByteArray` from an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 19):

### Java:   `(a = b) != c`

### Kotlin: `b.also { a = it } != c`

---

Unlike the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36887668/5318303), I recommend using Kotlin's **`also`** function, instead of `let`:

```
while (input.read(bytes).also { tmp = it } != -1) { ...
```

Because `T.also` returns `T` (`it`) itself and then you can compare it with `-1`. This is more similar to **Java's assignment as an expression**.

---

See *"Return this vs. other type"* section on [this useful blog](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) for details.

Comment: Idea's automatic java to kotlin conversion does this too

Answer (score 12):

Assignments [are not expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596261/kotlin-why-is-this-syntax-not-valid) in Kotlin, thus you'll need to do it outside:

```
var a: Int? = 1
var b: Int? = 2
var c: Int? = 1

a = b
if (a != c)
    print(true)
```

For your other example with `InputStream` you could do:

```
fun readFile(path: String) {
    val input: InputStream = FileInputStream(path)
    input.reader().forEachLine {
        print(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: im try to use i/o stream, so i have to put *a=b* in **if()** or **while()**, how should i do

Comment: sorry, here is my original code `fun readFile(path: String): Unit {
    var input: InputStream = FileInputStream(path)
    var string: String = ""
    var tmp: Int = -1
    var bytes: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
    while((tmp=input.read(bytes))!=-1){
        
    }
}`

Comment: Note: `reader` and `forEachLine` are not quite suitable for all the cases of an arbitrary byte stream, at least not with default (thus undefined) encoding which might not be single byte one and can fail at decoding the bytes. `InputStream::readBytes` is better for that.

Answer (score 12):

As pretty much everyone here has pointed out, assignments are not expressions in Kotlin.  However, we *can* coerce the assignment into an expression using a function literal:

```
val reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)
var line: String? = null
while ({ line = reader.readLine(); line }() != null) {
    println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

```
 input.buffered(1024).reader().forEachLine {
            fos.bufferedWriter().write(it)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way in kotlin is

```
if (kotlin.run{ a=b; a != c}){ ... }
```