# How to use setter like obj.value = "" when the setter has return value?

Tags: kotlin

I have an android EditText which I'm setting the text property on.

Normally I'd use:

```
editText.text = "Mars"
```

But the setter returns a Editable so it seems Kotlin is trying to replace the returned Editable with a String which fails.

So the *"workaround"* is:

```
editText.setText("Mars")
```

Are there any prettier ways (instead of `setText()`) of setting the text when this type of setter is used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Kotlin, assignments are not expressions. Assignment expressions have few real use cases and tend to worsen the code readability, not to mention the `if (a = b)` bugs, so they were left out of the language. You can find more comments from the Kotlin Team in [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/assignment-not-allow-in-while-expression/339).

It is actually impossible to get the value returned from a Java setter using the `property = value` syntax, and the workaround you described is the valid way to get that value.

---

Kotlin property setters, in turn, cannot return a value, and, for example, a common Java idiom of returning `this` value for the calls chaining is expressed with Kotlin [functions with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver):

```
MyClass c = new MyClass()
        .setFoo(x)
        .setBar(y)
        .setBaz(z);
```

Kotlin (using [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html)):

```
val c = MyClass().apply {
    foo = x
    bar = y
    baz = z
}
```

---

See also:

- [How to convert Java assignment expression to Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879236/how-to-convert-java-assignment-expression-to-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the info about Java vs Kotlin assignment expressions.