# Java-to-Kotlin translation bug

Tags: kotlin

Using the latest Kotlin 1.3.10 plugin from the latest IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3, if I translate the following Java code to Kotlin:

```
    BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filename"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
```

I get this:

```
    val br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filename"))
    var line: String
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        println(line)
```

The `while ((line = br.nextLine()) != null)` is idiomatic Java, but its automatic translation results in illegal syntax because assignments in Kotlin are not expressions.

1. Is this a known bug in the Java-to-Kotlin translator?
2. What's the Kotlin idiomatic syntax equivalent to the above Java code?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25765

Comment: I suppose that declaration at an upper level is the only way

Comment: Partly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879236/how-to-convert-java-assignment-expression-to-kotlin

Comment: It is a known bug, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments have answered both of my questions, so let me compile them into a single answer.

1. Yes, it's a known bug, reported at [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6294](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6294). You can vote for it (if you have a Jetbrains account) to show the developers that you would like it fixed. Thank you Alexey Belkov for bringing this to my attention.
2. A common way to directly translate it would be:

   ```
   val br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filename"))
   var line: String
   while (br.readLine().also { line = it} != null)
       println(line)
   ```

   However, a better way in this particular case is:

   ```
   val br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filename"))
   br.forEachLine {
       println(it)
   }
   ```

   Or just

   ```
   File("filename").forEachLine {
       println(it)
   }
   ```

   (which uses a convenience method, equivalent to Java's convenience method `Files.lines(Path)`).