# Assignments are not expressions and only expressions are allowed in this context - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting error while converting java to kotlin and cannot understand how to solve this particular error.

```
internal fun getDiff(to: Calendar, from: Calendar): Long {

        var diffInSeconds = (to.time.time - from.time.time) / 1000

        val diff = longArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0)
        diff[3] = if (diffInSeconds >= 60) diffInSeconds % 60 
                    else diffInSeconds // sec
        diff[2] = if ((diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 60)>= 60)
                         diffInSeconds % 60
                 else
                        diffInSeconds // min
        diff[1] = if ((diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 60) >= 24)
                        diffInSeconds % 24
                 else
                        diffInSeconds // hour
        diff[0] = (diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 24) // day

        Log.e("days", diff[0].toString() + "")

        return diff[0]
}
```

Following line: `(diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 60)` shows error displaying

> Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in
>   this context

Comment: have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596753/5110595)

Comment: the error is self explanatory, you are doing assignment at a place where the compiler is expecting an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do things like this:

```
diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 60
```

in if, it is not supported by kotlin.
You have to extract it before or after if.

E.g.

```
internal fun getDiff(to: Calendar, from: Calendar): Long {

    var diffInSeconds = (to.time.time - from.time.time) / 1000

    val diff = longArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0)
    diff[3] = if (diffInSeconds >= 60) diffInSeconds % 60
    else diffInSeconds // sec
    diffInSeconds /= 60
    diff[2] = if (diffInSeconds >= 60)
        diffInSeconds % 60
    else
        diffInSeconds // min
    diffInSeconds /= 60
    diff[1] = if (diffInSeconds >= 24)
        diffInSeconds % 24
    else
        diffInSeconds // hour
    diffInSeconds /= 24
    diff[0] = (diffInSeconds) // day


    return diff[0]
}
```

Comment: What if i store the expression in another variable and check it everytime?

Comment: It depends what do you want to do with it. You can create one more var and there store your if parameter without changing your main value.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not valid, because `diffInSeconds = diffInSeconds / 60` is not an expression in Kotlin. just do this

```
var a = diffInSeconds /= 60
diff[1] = if (a >= 24)
```

Comment: for each iteration you have to follow this way.