# How to do multiple variable assignments in one line in Kotlin like C,C++?

Tags: kotlin

I had to swap 2 numbers in one line expression using no other variable except x and y.
So I wrote the following `.c` program to swapp two numbers with the given conditions and it works like charm.

```
int main() {
    
    int x =5, y =2;
    x = y-x+(y=x);
    printf("X=%d, y=%d", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

But when i try to do the same in kotlin it gives me an error that

> Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in
> this context,

I can resolve this issue by introducing a third variable just [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477310/assignments-are-not-expressions-and-only-expressions-are-allowed-in-this-context). But I'm not allowed to have any other variable except x and y which are already given. So is there any other way I can do this in one line using any kotlin property?

Below is the kotlin program

```
fun main() {
    
    var x = 5
    var y = 10
    x = y-x+(y=x)   
    println("X = $x, Y = $y")

}
```

Comment: are you required to use one line, or is the only restriction that you can't use a 3rd variable?

Comment: Kotlin doesn’t support that, but you can do `a = b.also { b = a }`

Comment: @nigh_anxiety in one line expression without any 3rd variable, just like i did in c.

Comment: if the requirement is a single line, then `x = x+y; y = x-y; x = x-y` does the trick.  If it has to be a single statement then TenFour's suggestion of `x = y.also{y = x}` appears to work when testing in a Kotlin playground

Comment: Why do you want to do this though? Kotlin isn't C, and although you can technically do this stuff on a single written line, the bytecode it gets compiled to will create extra variables and generally be more verbose (*nigh_anxiety*'s example aside!). If it's about neat, efficient memory tricks, it's not really that kind of language. If it's about conciseness, just do the `also` thing, or write a reusable `swap` function that takes property references so you can go `swap(::a, ::b)` or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have two suggestions below, I want to start with a recommendation against either of them, at least in this simple example.

It's usually a lot more clear to optimise code for developers to read in the following ways:

- create an extra variable with a descriptive name
- prefer `val` over `var` to avoid accidental mutations
- and try to make the code 'linear', so the operations can be read from top-to-bottom without jumping between functions
- avoid code that needs an IDE to see what the type-hints are

And I'll trust that the compiler will make make the code performant.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val x = 5
  val y = 10

  val newX = y
  val newY = x

  println("X = $newX, Y = $newY")
}
```

##### Local function

You could use a [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#local-functions) to perform the swap, as the function will still be able to access the original values.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  var x = 5
  var y = 10

  fun swap(originalX: Int, originalY: Int) {
    y = originalX
    x = originalY
  }

  swap(x, y)

  println("X = $x, Y = $y")
}
```

##### Scope function

This could be code-golfed into one line

- use [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) to create a `Pair<Int, Int>`,
- and a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) to use the result.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  var x = 5
  var y = 10

  (x to y).apply { x = second; y = first }

  println("X = $x, Y = $y")
}
```

One line? Yes. More difficult to read? I think so.

Comment: “Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.” — Abelson & Sussman, _Structure And Interpretation Of Computer Programs_, preface to the 1st edition

Answer (score 0):

> I had to swap 2 numbers in one line expression using no other variable except x and y.

Using only two variables can sometimes be reasonable, given extreme constraints (like working solely with a small set of CPU registers, etc.), although that wouldn't typically apply to the use cases for a high-level language like Kotlin.

However, writing it all in one line is definitely not reasonable; it just makes it pointlessly harder to read.  Don't do that.

---

The common way to swap two variables without a temporary is this (as written in Kotlin):

```
x = x xor y
y = x xor y
x = x xor y
```